# Java Conversion issue - Int to string and again

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, performance, sorting

I am trying to make an integer to string to make slicing operation but the program doesn't gives me any answer it always gives the empty arraylist and While I see the modulus function simply returns the left but i want the modulus to return there.

```
public class My_first {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                int left =1, right=22;
                ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<>();
                while(left<=right){
                        String number = Integer.toString(left);
                        int count =0;
                        for(int i=0;i<number.length();i++){
                                if(left % (int) number.charAt(i) == 0){
                                        count++;
                                }
                        }
                        left++;
                        if (count >=number.length()){
                                num.add(left);
                        }
                }
                System.out.println(num);
        }
}
```

Can anyone help me find out what is this issue here..
The output is to be {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,15,22}.

Thank you in advance!!!!!

Comment: Avoid using underscores in your class name (though it works)

Comment: `left % (int) number.charAt(i) == 0` is never true, which means count never becomes greater than `number.length()` which means nothing is added to the array

Comment: Secondly your incrementing left before adding it to the array list, this means 1 will never end up in ur final list.

Comment: to convert a String to integer you can use `Integer.parseInt(String)` or, in this case, since it is a single digit, `number.charAt(i) - '0'`, but `(int) number.charAt(i)` will return the code-point of that character (e.g. `'0'` is actually the integer `48`)

Comment: What have you found out while debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a logical error in the modulus operation. The issue is with the expression `(int) number.charAt(i)`. This line doesn't convert the character to its integer value, but rather to its ASCII value, which is not what you intend.

Try using [`Character.getNumericValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue-int-) instead:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyFirst {

    /**
     * Finds all numbers between left and right (inclusive) where each digit of the number
     * divides the number itself.
     *
     * @param left The starting number of the range.
     * @param right The ending number of the range.
     * @return An ArrayList containing numbers that meet the criteria.
     */
    public static ArrayList<Integer> findDivisibleNumbers(int left, int right) {
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        while (left <= right) {
            String number = Integer.toString(left);
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
                int digit = Character.getNumericValue(number.charAt(i));
                if (digit != 0 && left % digit == 0) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count == number.length()) {
                numbers.add(left);
            }
            left++;
        }
        return numbers;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = findDivisibleNumbers(1, 22);
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 15, 22]
```

**Other changes:**

- Added a check for `digit != 0` to handle the case where `left` contains '0', as modulo by zero is undefined.
- Removed the underscore from your class name since that's unusual.
- Moved the algorithm into a separate method with corresponding Javadoc comment for increased readability and easy unit testing.

---

An alternate approach using streams for the culture:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public static ArrayList<Integer> findDivisibleNumbers(int left, int right) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(left, right)
                    .filter(num -> {
                        String numberStr = Integer.toString(num);
                        return numberStr.chars()
                                        .map(Character::getNumericValue)
                                        .allMatch(digit -> digit != 0 && num % digit == 0);
                    })
                    .boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}
```